# Using toString correctly

Tags: java

I am working on some home work and cannot figure out how to call the toString methods from the Point, Square and Cube classes to print out. I know it has to be something stupid, I think I am just toast and my mind is spent. Right now I have ??? in place where the toSting methods should go. Have tried every combination ("class".toString, etc) I can think of. Can anyone tell me where I am messing up?  Thanks!!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class InheritanceTest {

public static void main(String args[]){
    // Declare variables
    String xString = null;
    String yString = null;
    String sideString = null;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int sideLength = 0;

    try{
        xString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter x coordinate:");
        x = Integer.parseInt(xString);
        yString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter y coordinate:");
        y = Integer.parseInt(yString);
        sideString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter side of Square:");
        sideLength = Integer.parseInt(sideString);
        } // End try

        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(  null,"The value you entered is not a valid number. Please try again",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } // End catch

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Point: \n" +????????, "Results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
} // End main           

}// End Class

class Point{

//Declare variables
private int x;
private int y;

// Point constructor
Point(int xCoordinate,int yCoordinate){
x = xCoordinate;
y = yCoordinate;
}// End Point Constructor

// Accessor to return x coordinate
public int getX(){
    return x;
}// End getX method

// Accessor to return y coordinate
public int getY(){
    return y;
}// End getY method

// Format and display coordinates
public String toString(){
    return "Corner = [" + x + "," + y + "]\n";
}// End toString

}// End Point Class

abstract class Square extends Point{

//Declare variables
private double sideLength;

// Square constructor
Square(int x, int y, double s){
    super(x, y);
    sideLength = s;
} // End Square constructor

// Accessor to return side length
public double getSide(){
    return sideLength;
} // End getSide

// Method to calculate area of square
public double area(){
    return sideLength * sideLength;
} // End area method 

// Method to calculate perimeter of square
public double perimeter(){
    return 4 * sideLength;
} // End perimeter method

// Format and display the square
public String toString(){
    return super.toString() + "Side length is: " + sideLength + "\n" +
                "Area is: " + area() + "\n" + "Perimeter is: " + perimeter();
} // End toString
}// End Square Class

abstract class Cube extends Square{

// Declare variable
double depth;

// Cube constructor
public Cube(int x, int y, double s, double z){
super(x, y, s);
depth = z;
} // End Cube constructor

// Method to calculate area of cube
public double area(){
    return 6 * super.area();
} // End Area

// Method  to calculate volume of cube
public double volume(){
    return super.area() * depth;
} // End volume

// Format and display the cube
public String toString(){
    return "Depth is: " + depth + "\n" + "Area is: " + area() + "\n" + "Volume is: " + volume();
} // End toString
} // End Cube class
```

Comment: You first have to create an instance of one of the classes, for example: `Square sq = new Square(x, y, sideLength);`, then you can call `toString` on `sq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't invoke the toString() method from a Class, you invoke it from an object (i.e. an instance of that Class). It's `obj.toString()` where `obj` is an instance of Point, Square or Cube (or any other class).

I don't see you instantiating any objects of those classes, though. You need to create an instance of the class before you can invoke an instance-based method like toString().

```
Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
String pointString = myPoint.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to create an instance of the class that you want to work with first, for example:

```
Square s = new Square(10, 10, 2.0);
System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Comment: Do you really need a toString()? I thought System.out.println method needs to convert the argument into some string representation anyways before it can spit out anything to the console. In order to that what else should it invoke other toString().

Comment: @braindead Not entirely sure what you mean, but yes if you just do `System.out.println(s)` it will work as well, it calls `String.valueOf(Object o)` which in turn will call `o.toString`, so you're right it will call it anyway (indirectly).

Answer (score 1):

```
new Point(x,y).toString()
```

toString() is a method of the Point class. You need to instantiate it first with x and y coordinates then call its toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
"Point: \n" + new Point(x, y).toString, 
"Results", 
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```